# Natbib order of appearance starts again in new section

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I've been using the natbib package to sort my citations in order of appearance

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

But when I start a new \section for some reason the whole thing sorts again for some reason.

[image]

On page 12, where you can clearly see that the cite before is 8 and then 1, This is because when I've cited all the way down on page 27 its the same reference. That's the problem, I don't know why the citations resets, I guess, when is added in a new \section?

[image]

I do not know how to fix this. I'm kind of new to citations with latex and natbib. If it helps somehow, I'm using overleaf.com.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Point of order: It's not the `natbib` citation management package but the *bibliography style*, i.e., the argument of `\bibliographystyle` (here: `unsrtnat`), that determines the sorting order.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. Please also show us the code that generates the citation call-outs currenlty labelled `[1]`, `[8]` and `[9]`.

Comment: `\citep{lego_ev3_hdk}` is for `[1]`, `\citep{arkin1998behavior}` is for `[8]` and, `\citep{Jennings1997CooperativeSA}` is for `[9]`. And the document class is article

Maybe I'm not supposed to be using citep?